# Can anyone tell me which is the best way to test abn web application

Tags: testing, manual, software-quality

I am a QA engineer ,I would like to know what are the methods that i can follow to test a web application. What does and doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

That's rather a broad question you've asked.

Here are a few articles to get you started on testing the web applications:

- [How can a Web site be tested?](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/how-can-a-web-site-be-tested/)
- [Web Testing: Complete guide on testing web applications](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/web-application-testing/).

Good luck! ;)

Comment: The first link now redirects to the second link. I tried to edit this by removing the first link because the second link has all the information but it got rejected. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You could check Selenium for automating some actions that are performed by end users of your web application. That way you could create (business) acceptance tests which would be a whole scenarios e.g.:

Open site X, login with credentials, change password in the panel, logout, check if you can login again etc.
Or you might use Selenium for creating more atomic (smaller) tests that would test one particular behavior in your web application.

Selenium comes in two main "versions", Selenium IDE and Selenium Web driver. The first one is installed just as a Firefox (or other web browser) Extension/Add-on and allows you to record most of actions performed on the site. It does not require any programming skills to use for simple scenarios. The 2nd option is programming your tests using the Web driver and a language of your choice (Java, python, c# etc.). The second approach is much easier to manage when your tests are becoming larger and there is a lot of them. Plus, it gives you more flexibility with your tests (my opinion).

The others ways for testing web application may be measure its performance. You might use Chrome Dev Tools for it or write your own scripts. If your web application is making calls to web services be it a REST or SOAP ones you might use Fiddler to validate its response.

Fully manual tests are much easier to perform and also check for regression if they are well documented. So using some tools for managing your tests is also a good idea. The important thing about testing GUI of your web app is checking it on different browsers (do not forget about IE8 if your user base might be using it). There are quite a lot of commercial or free tools (some restrictions usually) to checking your app in dozens of different browser and versions.

Comment: Well can i perform functionality testing using selenium in any version?

Comment: Yes you can create functional tests with Selenium IDE and/or Selenium WebDriver. I think you should read a bit more about testing in general and different types of tests. After doing so it should be quite easy to get started with Selenium IDE and functional testing.